# Can I Force Feed someone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Say, hypothetically, I had someone trapped in an inescapable cage of warded blocks. Say also that I had removed their items and armor before transporting them there. They would eventually starve to death though. Could I prevent this by force feeding them in some way?

Comment: Purely hypothetical, of course, right?

Comment: .........right?

Comment: Absolutely right.

Comment: Does Regeneration from a level-four Beacon replenish health faster than hunger depletes it?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Yeah, I just did the math (see my answer).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could place a [beacon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Beacon) nearby that would give them a [regeneration buff](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effect). [Starvation](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger) causes a loss of 1 point every 4 seconds, while a level 1 regeneration buff gives 1 point every 25 ticks (or 1.25 seconds), so you should be able to keep them at full health even when their hunger bar is empty.

Comment: @fredley: For the record, I will be avoiding this *hypothetical* Minecraft Gitmo you're making. =p

Comment: *Hypothetically* making.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't force feed someone, you could just change the setting to easy so that they can't starve to death, as @ZAD-Man said. You could have a dispenser with splash potions of health every few minutes as to prevent them from dying though. You could put cakes everywhere, but there is nothing that you can do to forcibly feed someone.